# Require a certain (or later) version of a package?

Tags: packages, conditionals, compiling, datetime

Is there a way to enforce that a certain version, or a later version, of a package is loaded when building the document? I've found that compiling a document on another platform, where the package versions differ, can cause problems that may or may not be hard to pinpoint. Thus, I would like to be able to say, in the document, that "you need at least this version of this package", and produce an explicit error about it when it doesn't hold true.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I think [Is it possible to abort loading a package if it's too old?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33806/is-it-possible-to-abort-loading-a-package-if-its-too-old) should answer that. Note that you can state a minimal version/date using the trailing optional argument of `\usepackage[<options>]{<name>}[<min.date>]` (or `\RequirePackage`). Then there is `\@ifpackagelater{<name>}{<date>}{<yes>}{<no>}` as shown in the linked thread.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I think the present question is more general than the one you linked to. That said, your comment would make a fine answer.

Comment: @lockstep: Ok, makes sense. I posted an answer. Thanks.

Comment: See also [Which package version am I using? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can request a minimal version/date using the trailing optional argument of `\usepackage[<options>]{<name>}[<min.date>]` (or `\RequirePackage`). However, it will only print a warning text and not cause an error if the installed version is older than the requested version.

This feature is realized in the LaTeX core by the macro `\@ifpackagelater{<name>}{<date>}{<yes>}{<no>}`, which you can also use yourself (`\makeatletter` .. `\makeatother` is required if not used inside a package or class file).

The `<date>` must be in the format `year/month/day`, e.g. 2022/08/10 for August 10th, 2022.

You can use the following code to cause an error if the package is older than the given date. However, this only works *after* the package was loaded.

```
\makeatletter
\usepackage{<name>}%
\@ifpackagelater{<name>}{<date>}{%
    % Package is new enough
}{%
    \PackageError{<your package or document name>}{Package <name> is to old <...>}%
}
\makeatother
```

Note that despite the name `\@ifpackagelater`, AFAIK, the macro checks actually if the package date is later or equal. A more accurate name would be therefore `ifpackagenotolder`. If you want to check if a package is actually newer than a last version known to you, than simply add one day to the date.

---

Here an example based on the `mwe` package which also checks if the package is installed at all:

```
\IfFileExists{mwe.sty}{%
    \RequirePackage{mwe}%
    \@ifpackagelater{mwe}{2018/03/30}{%
        % Package version new enough
    }{%
        % Package version too old
    }
}{%
   % Package not installed
}
```

Comment: After trying it, this answer is not entirely accurate as you must _first_ load the package (i.e. do `\usepackage`) and _then_ check whether it is too old (i.e. do `\@ifpackagelater`). The reason being that `\@ifpackagelater` checks a variable `var@<package>` which is not available (and will thus produce an error) until you've loaded the package.

Comment: @gablin: I corrected my answer now. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Also note that the <date> must be supplied as <year/month/day>.

Comment: can you provide a full example of how this would be used?

Comment: @FrederickNord: Done

Answer (score 4):

In newer LaTeX versions, `\@ifpackagelater` can also be `\IfPackageAtLeastTF`.

[image: source2e.pdf snippet]

Usage is identical.