# Tikz version history information

Tags: tikz-pgf, package-writing

I'm working on a package that works on top of tikz. It needs certain libraries (the tikz libraries `quotes`, `positioning` and `intersections` and the pgf library `arrows.meta`). Is there any way I can determine which versions of Tikz support the features I need? For instance, if there is a repository somewhere with the previous versions of the Tikz source, it would be really useful.

As it is, I've been using trial and error -- certain of that my friends have versions of Tikz that are definitely too old, and certain of my friends have versions which are recent enough, so I currently know that as of June 2012, Tikz did not have all the features I need, and as of September 2014, it did. This seems really ad hoc though.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47743/require-a-certain-or-later-version-of-a-package The details are given in the log file for the packages if you place `\listfiles` in the preamble

Comment: There has been not so many "official" TikZ versions if we consider only CTAN ones. Last in CTAN is: 3.0.1a from 2015-08-29. In any case you can always consult [TikZ development site in sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/?source=directory) and browse through [cvs repository](http://pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pgf/).

Comment: @percusse I don't think my question is a duplicate of that one. I know how `\@ifpackagelater` and related things work, what I want to know is which versions of Tikz my package will work with. My current method of determining whether my package works with a certain old version of tikz is to luck into finding a TeX installation with that version.

Comment: @Ignasi Do either of those sites have older versions of the code? As far as I can tell, both of them only have version 3.0.1a. The version number itself "3.0.1a" suggests to me that there probably have been quite a few versions, since presumably there were at least versions 3.0.0 and 3.0.1 too.

Comment: I don't know how but I think a cvs system allows to go back to previous versions. In any case I think there's no problem in updating previous versions to recent ones, almost all packages (TikZ within them) are backwards compatible.

Comment: @Ignasi -- It's true that in general updating tikz is pretty easy and has no drawbacks. People just don't like having to do it. Also, my work computer uses Fedora, and I couldn't actually figure out how to get the most recent version of tikz -- apparently Linux versions of TeX don't have the normal package manager that comes on windows and mac versions of TeX for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm a MikTeX+Windows user, but on all TeX systems is possible to have a "local tree" where you can install "personal" packages. May be http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz/5702#5702 can help you with this problem.