# Dual compatibility of TeX sources

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling

Consider the following situation. You enjoy TeXing on your local machine, having fun with the latest versions of various packages. For example, exploiting the benefits of `TikZ/externalize`... or `biblatex`.

Alas... Your university's TeX installation is old, or your collaborator cannot use your cutting edge packages. Then, a checked out copy on the other system **won't compile!**

One solution, which I have just used, is to remove all the fancy stuff from the source and make it compatible with the old-style system. This, however, has huge disadvantages; for example now compiling your source (on you local box) takes longer because you cannot take advantage of your latest installed version of `TikZ`.

Let me focus on the `TikZ` issue. Is there a way to automize a solution? That is, run a test at the beginning of the compilation, and *enable* or *disable* the usage of the `externalize` package depending on the system the document is currently compiled on?

Does this kind of approach make sense at all?

### Edit:

I'm taking the risk of becoming too localized, but I do want to find a solution and to accept an answer here. I tired to use @JosephWright idea as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\IfFileExists{tikzexternal.sty}
{%
  \usetikzlibrary{external}%
  \tikzexternalize%
  \tikzsetexternalprefix{figures/cache/}%
  \renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{%
    \tikzexternaldisable\@todo[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}%
}%
{%
}%
\makeatother
```

When compiling this I get the following error: `Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.` which I don't know how to fix... Any ideas?

Comment: Are you after something as simple as `\@ifpackagelater`?

Comment: @JosephWright: I'm not sure. If the system doesn't support the `externalize` library of `TikZ`, then I trying to load it will yield an error, and I won't get a chance to check whether it was loaded or not.

Comment: Then perhaps `\IfFileExists` first (for the `.code.tex` file)

Comment: @JosephWright: Sounds in the right direction. Can you point to some reference or expand this to an answer? :) A quick look around yielded nothing.

Comment: Your edit would probably be better as a second linked question. Brief answer: double the `#`.

Comment: Related Question: [Is it possible to abort loading a package if it's too old?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33806/is-it-possible-to-abort-loading-a-package-if-its-too-old).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LaTeX provides two tools that will be useful here: `\IfFileExists` and `\@ifpackagelater`. If we take the case outlined in the question, we cannot be sure the file is even available. I'll generalise to a package `foo`, which might give something like

```
\makeatletter
\IfFileExists{foo.sty}
   {%
     % True branch
     \usepackage{foo}
     \@ifpackagelater{foo}{2012/10/23}
       {%
         % All good: use latest code
       }
       {%
         % Code older: fall back on something?
       }%
   }
   {%
     % False branch: backup plan
   }%
\makeatother
```

Note that `\@ifpackagelater` actually gives `TRUE` if the dates match, and requires a date from a LaTeX package (`\ProvidesPackage` line). Also notice that `\IfFileExists` looks for files in general, so we need the *full* name including the extension.

Comment: This seems to be what I was after. Unfortunately, before I can test it, I have to solve another issue... http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78882/412

Comment: When you write "looks for files in general..." you mean in the search path of TeX?

Comment: This is in the right direction! But, when I try to use the redefinition of my `\todo` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78882/412) in the "True branch" I get an error, saying: "Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a" Any idea what can be done?

Comment: Here is the complete code I'm trying to use: \makeatletter
\IfFileExists{tikzexternal.sty}
{%
  \usetikzlibrary{external}
  \tikzexternalize
  \tikzsetexternalprefix{figures/cache/}%
  \renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\@todo[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}%
}
{
}%
\makeatother

Comment: I would love to accept this answer, as it seems to be exactly what I'm after - but I'm still missing a part of the puzzle. Can someone help me here an bridge the gap?