# Preamble vs. external style file - same code doesn't work in the later

Tags: packages, preamble

I'm experiencing the following issue when using `todonotes` along with `TikZ` and its `externalize` library. If my document contains no `\todo`'s then it compiles just fine and seems like the externalization of TikZ does it trick. However, once there are `\todo`'s in the document, then some of them fail the compilation.

If I surround such a problematic `\todo` as follows:

```
 \begingroup
  \tikzexternaldisable
  \todo{Note's content}%
  \tikzexternalenable
  \endgroup
```

Then the compilation runs smoothly again.  So, the next step is naturally to re-define the `\todo`. Thus, in the preamble I added the following:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{%
  \begingroup \tikzexternaldisable
  \@todo[#1]{#2} \tikzexternalenable
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

and everything seems to be right. The problem I have is that I stuffed all my preamble in a separated `.sty` file. When I move the last snippet to the `.sty` file then the problem occurs again. (The last snippet is coming from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50343/412)). Otherwise, the `.sty` file loads correctly, as far as I can tell.

**Summary:** My question is why the *same* code when it is in the "main" file behaves as expected, but when it is moved to a style file which is loaded (correctly) it doesn't work anymore. I guess it has nothing to to in particular with neither `TikZ` nor `todonotes` - but I mention them as they caused a problem in my case.

Comment: What happens if you put only `\tikzexternalize` in your document instead of the style file?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question but in the package file *just* put

```
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{%
  \begingroup \tikzexternaldisable
  \@todo[#1]{#2} \tikzexternalenable
  \endgroup}
```

I suspect you put `\makeatother` in there which would flip the meaning of `@` so break any following uses of it in the package.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not the case. Your suggestions didn't help. Thanks anyway!

Comment: sometimes you without an MWE you guess wrong:-) (but I see you note that in your answer:-)